# Can't login after overriding default user model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

I have customized default Django model and now after creating a new superuser I can't login.
It says that login or password is invalid.

models.py:

```py
class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email is required")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            password = password
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    GENDERS = (
        ("Male", "Male"),
        ("Female", "Female"),
        ("Other", "Other")
    )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDERS, max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

settings.py:

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "UserProfile.UserProfile"
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

So when I create a new superuser and try to login in admin panel I get an error " Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account."
I've already tried deleting database and migrations.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try Base User Manager as**

*Please customize field as your need, i am just writing basics*

```
def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
    

def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

*Password = Password doesn't usually save hashed password, That's why you can't save password directly without user save method.*

Comment: Thank you, it works! But can you please tell me how can I implement same thing with the code i showed in question? I tried changing Password = Password to `user.set_password(password)`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: **welcome, if you approve the answer this can be helpful for others also**, and in your code you don't have _create_user function, it may be the cause, try using _create_user function before create user, and write `user.set_password(password)` in _create_user function not in create user function.